# Select Parent and Child Collection to a List of some model simultaniously in C# Linq

Tags: c#, linq

The Class Boss has the sub Class Collection Person for representing List of Employees under him/her.

> **My Requirement** is to get the list of persons `List<Person> Members`
>   from the **object `John`** using LINQ Statement.

```
public class Person
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
}

public class Boss
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Gender { get; set; }
    public List<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}

Boss John = new Boss()
{
    Name = "Harry",
    Department = "Development",
    Gender = "Male",
    Employees = new List<Person>()
        {
            new Person() {Name = "Peter", Department = "Development",Gender = "Male"},
            new Person() {Name = "Emma Watson", Department = "Development",Gender = "Female"},

        }
}
```

My Required Collection should be

```
List<Person> Members = new List<Person>()
    {
        new Person() {Name = "Harry", Department = "Development",Gender = "Male"},
        new Person() {Name = "Peter", Department = "Development",Gender = "Male"},
        new Person() {Name = "Emma Watson", Department = "Development",Gender = "Female"},
    }
```

How to achieve the List Members from the **object `John`** using LINQ Statement. Kindly assist me.

Kindly provide the Solution also for **`Distinct List<Person> Members`** from **`List<Boss>`** using LINQ Statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can simply do it like this:

```
var list = John.Employees.ToList();

list.Insert(0,
    new Person
    {
        Name = John.Name,
        Department =  John.Department,
        Gender = John.Gender
    });
```

If you have a `List<Boss>`, then you can do something like this:

```
var result = list
    .SelectMany(x =>
        new [] { new Person { Name = x.Name, Department = x.Department, Gender = x.Gender, EmpID = x.EmpID }}
        .Concat(x.Employees))
    .GroupBy(x => x.EmpID) //Group by employee ID
    .Select(g => g.First()) //And select a single instance for each unique employee
    .ToList();
```

Comment: What can I do for List<Boss> ?

Comment: What would be the output in this case? How would you handle duplicates?

Comment: Yes. I need a Distinct List of Members from the List<Boss>

Comment: Just add one more property EmpID

Answer (score 2):

You can use LINQ [Concat](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb302894(v=vs.110).aspx) like this:

```
var Members = 
    new [] { new Person { Name = John.Name, Department = John.Department, Gender = John.Gender } }
    .Concat(John.Employees)
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using inheritance:

```
public class Boss : Person
{
    public List<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

And then you can create the list you want by using:

```
var result = new List<Person> { John };
result.AddRange(John.Employees);
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your `Boss` and `Person` classes share 3 properties, you could go with inheritance

```
public class Boss : Person
{
    public List<Person> Employees { get; set; }
}
```

It would be good to have another `Employee` class though

```
public class Employee : Person
{
    public int EmpID { get; set; }
}
```

Then you could simply do

```
List<Person> members = new Person[] { John }
                       .Concat(John.Employees)
                       .ToList();
```

As for the `List<Boss>` you can do

```
List<Person> members2 = bosses.ToArray<Person>()
                              .Concat(bosses.SelectMany(x => x.Employees)
                                            .GroupBy(x => x.EmpID)
                                            .Select(g => g.First()))
                              .ToList<Person>();
```

Please find a fully working fiddle [there](https://dotnetfiddle.net/N4w6lQ).